# Convert a dataframe to a vector (by rows)

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, r-faq

I have a dataframe with numeric entries like this one

```
test <- data.frame(x = c(26, 21, 20), y = c(34, 29, 28))
```

How can I get the following vector?

```
> 26, 34, 21, 29, 20, 28
```

I was able to get it using the following, but I guess there should be a much more elegant way

```
X <- test[1, ]
for (i in 2:dim(test)[ 1 ]){
   X <- cbind(X, test[i, ])
   }
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can try `as.vector(t(test))`. Please note that, if you want to do it by columns you should use `unlist(test)`.

Comment: I can not understand of this workaround. could give some more explanations? @teucer

Comment: @verystrongjoe there are two things going on here: 1) t implicitly converts a data.frame to a matrix, 2) a matrix is just a special vector with dim attribute and as.vector or c removes it

Comment: I had to use `as.numeric(t(df))`

Comment: `unlist` does not work if columns have different class. See `unlist(data.frame(a= 1:10, b= letters[1:10]))`, for example. I ended up using `do.call("c", lapply(data.frame(a= 1:10, b= letters[1:10]), function(i) as.character(i)))`

Answer (score 11):

```
c(df$x, df$y)
# returns: 26 21 20 34 29 28
```

if the particular order is important then:

```
M = as.matrix(df)
c(m[1,], c[2,], c[3,])
# returns 26 34 21 29 20 28
```

Or more generally:

```
m = as.matrix(df)
q = c()
for (i in seq(1:nrow(m))){
  q = c(q, m[i,])
}

# returns 26 34 21 29 20 28
```

Comment: Yes, order does matter, I want convertion by rows. And the rows are many more than 3. So it would be better if you could transform this to a loop or use a vectorized function. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this to get your combination:

```
as.numeric(rbind(test$x, test$y))
```

which will return:

```
26, 34, 21, 29, 20, 28
```