# How to extract a column / row attribute from a table in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that I have *any generic table* such as the following:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
|----------|----------|----------|
| Row 1    |          |          |
| Row 2    |          |          |
| Row 3    |          |          |
```

How can I pull the row and columns into a vector in R without manually imputing them?

I tried `c(table)`, where `table`is the table name, but that didn´t give me the output I expected.  I´m looking for the output of a vector containing, `c(Row 1, Row 2, Row 3,...)`, in addition a vector containing `c(Column 1, Column 2, Column 3,...)`.

I saw [Converting a dataframe to a vector (by rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545228/converting-a-dataframe-to-a-vector-by-rows), but it creates a vector such as `Column 1, Row 1, Column 2, Row 2` or vice versa, while I am looking for two seperate vectors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a dataframe to a vector (by rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545228/converting-a-dataframe-to-a-vector-by-rows)

Comment: @ang I saw that, but I am looking for two separate vectors, one for the column and one for the row.  That creates the vector for the column AND the row.

Comment: Please provide a real R object and exactly what the output would look like in R. What you're describing could perhaps be done using indexing (`$`, `[`) with a combination of `rownames` or `colnames`.

Comment: Do you mean a couple of vector with column names and row names? Maybe it is going to fit colnames(data) and rownames(data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data(iris)
df <- iris[, 1:4]
head(df) # have a look at df

rows.vec <- as.vector(t(df)) # first vector for rows
cols.vec <- as.vector(unlist(df)) # second vector for columns
```