# Change table to character vector without spaces

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, character

Let's have a following datafrane:

```
df <- data.frame(c("a", "c ","e "), c("b ", "d", "f "))
colnames(df) <- c("X1", "X2")
df
  X1 X2
1  a b 
2 c   d
3 e  f
```

How to transform the given data.frame to one character vector without spaces?

```
#Expected result:
#vector
#[1]"abcdef"
```

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545228/converting-a-dataframe-to-a-vector-by-rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution from base R.

```
paste(trimws(as.vector(t(df))), collapse = "")
# [1] "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 3):

Transpose `df`, unravel it into a vector, trim the spaces and paste the components together:

```
paste(trimws(c(t(df))), collapse = "")
## [1] "abcdef"
```

Comment: `c` is more efficient than `as.vector` in my solution. Thanks for sharing your solution

Comment: The documentation cautions against using `c` over `as.vector`. I agree, since it’s hard to read. `as.vector` makes the intentions clearer.

Comment: It claims as.vector is more intuitive. It does not warn against using it.  Note that some of the recommendations in the documentation are not the best.  For example, intidyverse would never have been developed in its current form had it followed recommendations in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

An idea using `gsub` to remove unwanted spaces,

```
gsub(' ', '', paste(unlist(t(df)), collapse =  ''))
#[1] "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, `t` already converts `df` to a matrix, so the following works:

```
paste(trimws(t(df)), collapse = "")
# [1] "abcdef"
```

Comment: `t(df)` is a matrix, so I am not sure why `as.matrix` is requried

Comment: Actually, `t(df)` is already a matrix, which means `paste(trimws(t(df)), collapse = "")
` works!

Comment: Good point! I love how each answer brings some improvements to the table.

Comment: @avid_useR This is the most concise and efficient answer so far. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

One option is `paste` after removing the leading/lagging spaces with `trimws`

```
paste(do.call(paste0, lapply(df, trimws)), collapse="")
#[1] "abcdef"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_all(str_squish) %>% 
  pmap_chr(paste, sep="") %>%
  paste(., collapse="")
#[1] "abcdef"
```