# For each unique timestamp in df, make vector of all rows in dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

How do I create a vector that contains multiple sensor values for each time stamp. The desired output in this subset of the data would be to group the three first rows since they have the exact same timestamp like:
([21, 0, 0, 5236],[6, 6, 0, 58],[18, 1, 0, 1770]) and then for the next timestamp etc.

Also, this has to be done without a for-loop since it's almost one million rows.

Comment: `print(df.to_dict())` and paste the output in your question, don't use images as they aren't reproducible.

Comment: Please don't post image of a dataframe, provide dataframe in text format so that people can copy and try their logic.

Comment: When I use print(df.to_dict()) I get something like: {'Report_Time': {5813: Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 5823: Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 5824:
How do I make it look like a df in my post?

Comment: the goal is to make your post replicable, if you post that output we can copy that into our IDEs and create your dataframe to test any solutions. you can just add it as one line

Comment: I've done that now, thank you. @Manakin

Comment: awesome you're very close to a [mcve] now you just need to add a sample of what you want your data to  look like.

Comment: @Manakin would you mind if i answer the question :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma please go ahead! you never need permission for good answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can `group` the dataframe on `Report_Time`, then for each group corresponding to unique `Timestamp` you can create a mapping from `Timestamp` to the required array obtained from the columns `A`, `B`, `Type` and `Meter_Value`  inside the `dict` comprehension:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'Type', 'Meter_Value']
info = {k: g[cols].to_numpy() for k, g in df.groupby('Report_Time')}
```

To access the arrays corresponding to a unique `Timestamp` you can use dictionary lookup:

```
>>> info[pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34')]

array([[21, 0, 0, '5236'],
       [6, 6, 0, '58'],
       [18, 1, 0, '1770'],
       [21, 0, 0, '5237']], dtype=object)

>>> info[pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35')]

array([[6, 6, 0, '57'],
       [19, 2, 0, '1732'],
       [21, 0, 0, '5238'],
       [18, 1, 0, '1769']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank You! This works as desired. Basically I have a single sensor-value on each row, but the amount of rows is not consistent for unique timestamps. So I had an idea to remove seconds and look at all logged sensor-values/rows for each minute and maybe do dimensionality reduction for each minute. Do you know if this is possible even though the amount of rows will be different for each minute?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Timestamp changed, if it changed start to collect the rows in variables, afterwards get them vectored with `as.vector(t(Dataframevariable))`.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545228/convert-a-dataframe-to-a-vector-by-rows) post might help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 dct = {'Report_Time': {5813: pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 5823: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 5824: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 5825: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 5829: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 5830: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 5831: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 5839: 
                   pd.Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35')}, 
   'Subsystem': {5813: 0, 5823: 0, 5824: 0, 5825: 0, 5829: 0, 5830: 0, 5831: 0, 5839: 0}, 'A': {5813: 21, 5823: 6, 5824: 18, 5825: 21, 5829: 6, 5830: 19, 5831: 21, 5839: 18}, 'B': {5813: 0, 5823: 6, 5824: 1, 5825: 0, 5829: 6, 5830: 2, 5831: 0, 5839: 1}, 'Type': {5813: 0, 5823: 0, 5824: 0, 5825: 0, 5829: 0, 5830: 0, 5831: 0, 5839: 0}, 'Meter_Value': {5813: '5236', 5823: '58', 5824: '1770', 5825: '5237', 5829: '57', 5830: '1732', 5831: '5238', 5839: '1769'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df.columns)


grouped=df.groupby('Report_Time').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

results=[ (x.index,key, list(x))  for key,x in grouped.iteritems()]
print(results)
```

output:

```
[(DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-04 11:03:34', '2021-02-04 11:03:35'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Report_Time', freq=None), 'Subsystem', [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]), (DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-04 11:03:34', '2021-02-04 11:03:35'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Report_Time', freq=None), 'A', [[21, 6, 18, 21], [6, 19, 21, 18]]), (DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-04 11:03:34', '2021-02-04 11:03:35'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Report_Time', freq=None), 'B', [[0, 6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0, 1]]), (DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-04 11:03:34', '2021-02-04 11:03:35'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Report_Time', freq=None), 'Type', [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]), (DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-04 11:03:34', '2021-02-04 11:03:35'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Report_Time', freq=None), 'Meter_Value', [['5236', '58', '1770', '5237'], ['57', '1732', '5238', '1769']])]
```

In [ ]:

```
 tuples=[]
 for my_tuples in results:
     (dates,key,data)=my_tuples
     for i in range(len(dates)):
         print(dates[i],key,data[i])
         tuples.append((dates[i],key,data[i]))
for a_tuple in tuples:
    print(a_tuple)
```

output:

```
    Index(['Report_Time', 'Subsystem', 'A', 'B', 'Type', 'Meter_Value'], dtype='object')
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 'Subsystem', [0, 0, 0, 0])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 'Subsystem', [0, 0, 0, 0])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 'A', [21, 6, 18, 21])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 'A', [6, 19, 21, 18])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 'B', [0, 6, 1, 0])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 'B', [6, 2, 0, 1])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 'Type', [0, 0, 0, 0])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 'Type', [0, 0, 0, 0])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:34'), 'Meter_Value', ['5236', '58', '1770', '5237'])
   (Timestamp('2021-02-04 11:03:35'), 'Meter_Value', ['57', '1732', '5238', '1769'])
```

​

Comment: you can now use a list comprehension or other type of list tuple filtering to get the desired data.